# Gitlab webservice and sidekiq do not start

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I have a 8s cluster created with kubeadm (Server Version: v1.25.4).
There was Gitlab v15.11.13 running, which was installed with helm gitlab chart v6.11.13.

Everything worked fine, but I wanted to upgrade to the next version: v16.0.0. So I run these commands:

```bash
helm get values gitlab -n gitlab > gitlab-values.yaml

kubectl scale deployment --replicas 0 --selector 'app in (webservice, sidekiq, kas, gitlab-exporter)' --namespace gitlab

# The documentation says to remove redis statefulset before this upgrade
kubectl delete statefulset gitlab-redis-master --namespace gitlab

# I use the values pulled a minute ago without any changes
helm upgrade gitlab gitlab/gitlab -n gitlab --version 7.0.0 --values gitlab-values.yaml
```

However, the upgrade failed with the error

> Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', 'updateStrategy', 'persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy' and 'minReadySeconds' are forbidden

I had no time to fix it, so decided to redeploy the chart 6.11.13 which worked fine in the past:

```bash
helm upgrade gitlab gitlab/gitlab -n gitlab  --version  6.11.13 --values gitlab-values.yaml
```

However, it also doesn't work. The pods `webservice` and `sidekiq` have status "Init:2/3". The logs of those containers showed the same errors:

```
kubectl logs -n gitlab -c dependencies -f gitlab-sidekiq-all-in-1-v2-7bdc4ddd8c-gfmn8

Begin parsing .erb templates from /var/opt/gitlab/templates
Writing /srv/gitlab/config/cable.yml
Writing /srv/gitlab/config/database.yml
Writing /srv/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml
Writing /srv/gitlab/config/resque.yml
Begin parsing .tpl templates from /var/opt/gitlab/templates
Copying other config files found in /var/opt/gitlab/templates to /srv/gitlab/config
Copying smtp_settings.rb into /srv/gitlab/config
- FAILED connecting to 'redis://gitlab-redis-master.gitlab.svc:6379' from resque.yml, through gitlab-redis-master.gitlab.svc
ERROR: Error connecting to Redis on gitlab-redis-master.gitlab.svc:6379 (Redis::TimeoutError)
Checking: resque.yml, cable.yml
Error checking main: connection to server at "10.106.237.84", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Checking: main
```

`Sidekiq` and `webservice` couldn't connect to the `redis` and `postgres`, which is strange because these services look good. I tried to forward the ports to the `postgres` and could connect to the DB from my laptop.

I tried to

1. removing the `sidekiq` and `webservice` deployments and restart `helm upgrade`.
2. restarting the server with k8s cluster.

But nothing helped and now the logs changed a little: there is no TIMEOUT error because the `dependencies` container is stuck one step earlier: `Copying smtp_settings.rb into /srv/gitlab/config`.

So, now I have the gitlab chart v6.11.13 released with exactly the same values as it had before, but doesn't work because the `webservice` and `sidekiq` are stuck on the stage of waiting for dependencies. I see no errors.

Have no idea what else can I do here. Please, help

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. After reverting to the previous version, I found that the postgres service has more selectors than needed:

postgres service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgresql
    app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: gitlab
    app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
    release: gitlab
    role: master
```

While the statefulset has:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgresql
        chart: postgresql-8.9.4
        heritage: Helm
        release: gitlab
        role: master
```

So, I removed the

```
app.kubernetes.io/component: primary
app.kubernetes.io/instance: gitlab
app.kubernetes.io/name: postgresql
```

and everything started to work.